# Getting Linux computer integrated with Windows domain

Tags: windows, samba, domain

I've tried to figure it out for several months, with no success. I have a Windows 2008R2 domain, and one Linux server (first it was Fedora 15, then 16, and now it's Centos 6.2). I am trying to make it member of the domain to the extent possible. Ideally, I would like to login and get authenticated against domain (say, login 'DOMAIN+john'). If not - at least be able to map directories through Samba with Windows credentials (better, map drives without specifying credentials, and just passing Windows credentials).

I followed several articles, most closely [this one](http://home.roadrunner.com/~computertaijutsu/adsamba.html); but still can't map the drive (as soon as I switch security from USER to ADS, I can't expand the server)... let alone login. I know I am close (eg., I am getting `pam_get_item returned a password` from winbind when I log in) - but pointers to something definitive would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [www.likewiseopen.org](http://www.likewiseopen.org)

My colleagues at work succeeded to join the AD using their Ubuntu machines, but I couldn't do it on my Debian...
I don't think you can do it jusing just Samba.

Comment: I rebuild the machine (fortunately, I just started to set it up, so it was easier to start from scratch than to undo all the changes that I tried) and I *was* able to set everything up using PowerBroker Identity Services (formerly likewise open) at the link above!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have already looked at this but there are at lease 2 wikis on point here:

- [Integrating Samba with Active Directory](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory)
- [Authenticating against Windows Domain](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba,_Active_Directory_%26_LDAP)

There is also a big article on [Enterprise Networking Planet](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netos/article.php/3487081/Join-Samba-3-to-Your--Active-Directory-Domain.htm) on how to get this done.

Comment: yes - I started with samba.org articles; should have mentioned that, of course! But didn't see the other one. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix Anytime.

Comment: I gave up doing it manually. PBIS from BeyondTrust automated the whole process :D

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a fair amount of the necessary bits on the Gentoo Wiki here: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kerberos_Windows_Interoperability

It is a distillation of many wiki pages, blogs and personal experience.